# How to add auto play setting in Carousel Slider

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel

I have  jQuery Carousel Slider Plugin with rows.

i want add to Carousel  auto play setting

there is Carousel Slider - [Demo](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-jQuery-Layout-Carousel-Slider-Plugin-RadiantScroller/)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var sc = $('#myScroller').radiantScroller({
elementWidth: 400,
cols: 2,
rows: 2,
useMouseWheel: true,
addPagination: true
});
});
</script>
```

i added this code :

```
 autoplay: true,   autoplaySpeed: 2000,
```

but it is not working

Comment: check my answer i have added auto play setting to your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plugin you used is not provide auto play feature  check document [here](https://github.com/bodrovis/RadiantScroller)

check example on [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/6xcqhr7h/) i have added auto play setting using RadiantScroller's API and callbackfunctions

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

 var sc;
 sc = $('#myScroller').radiantScroller({
   elementWidth: 400,
   cols: 3,
   rows: 2,
 loaded : function(){ 
    setTimeout(function(){
          sc.radiantScroller('next');
    },2000)  
 },
 afterMove : function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
          sc.radiantScroller('next');
   },2000) 
 },
 lastPageReached : function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
          sc.radiantScroller(1);
   },2000) 
 }  
 });
});
```

Comment: on your  example it is working, but i didnot uderstend where add this code 
 var sc;
 sc = $('#myScroller').radiantScroller({
   elementWidth: 400,
   cols: 3,
   rows: 2,
 loaded : function(){ 
    setTimeout(function(){
          sc.radiantScroller('next');
    },2000)  
 },
 afterMove : function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
          sc.radiantScroller('next');
   },2000) 
 },
 lastPageReached : function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
          sc.radiantScroller(1);
   },2000) 
 }  
});

Comment: have you create any example ? then share it on your question . full page

Comment: i have updated answer . copy my code and replace with your javascript code

Comment: you are using old version of plugin . download latest file from here and check   https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/radiantwind/radiant_scroller/script/jquery.radiant_scroller.min.js